# Checking if an array is in bound or out of bound

Tags: c, arrays

So basically, I have this 2-D array that looks like this.

```
######...s
e......###
```

It suppose to print a * from s-e only if theres a "." , the "#" is like a wall.

So I check all the possible location but for some reason its not outputting a "*" to e.

I believe it because of something to do with it being out of bound.

I did some check for example like

```
if(array.x <=row && array.y<= col && array.x >=0 && array.y >=0)
```

Is this a proper way to check if I'm inside or out of bound?

Btw this is an 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `row` is the number of rows, `col` is the number of columns, `array.x` and `array.y` are the indices, a proper check for indices in bounds is:

```
if(0 <= array.x && array.x < row && 0 <= array.y && array.y < col) {
   ...
}
```

Note the strict inequality with `row` and `col`.

Comment: I believe for the last check I think you met "< col" not "<= col". I changed it in my code and it works. Thank you so so so much.